# Restoring In App Purchases for iOS using Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, restore, in-app-purchase

I want to create a button that allows the user to restore their In App purchases if they ever delete and re-install the game.

I am using Unity 4 for iOS specifically.

I have done this in objective-c using Cocos2D but I know that it does not work the same way.

Does anyone know any code snippets or links to a tutorial that can help me gain access to what has been purchased and restore these for the user?

Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe restoring transactions at the bottom of this page will help: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of plugin for StoreKit? There is a really nice plugin by Prime31 which provides this behavior:

```
public static void restoreCompletedTransactions();
```

You can visit their website for more information
http://prime31.com/docs#iosStoreKit

Comment: its only for ios. Then what about android?

Comment: For both Android & iOS you can try SOOMLA https://github.com/soomla/unity3d-store